# Identify all state variables are set

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have 2 check boxes with state variables "isApproved, setIsApproved" and "isPlayer, setIsPlayer"

After both of these values are assigned, I need to perform some operation say getDetails(isApproved, isPlayer)

The way I know if these 2 state variables are set is by using useEffect()

```
useEffect(()=>{
     getDetails(isApproved, isPlayer)
},[isApproved,isPlayer])
```

But the issue with this is, whenever user clicks on checkbox, one of these state variable value changes and again "getDetails" gets called

I want to call getDetails only for the first time after these 2 state variables are set

Any suggestions please?

Comment: To implement "first time" actions, one usually initializes a FirstTime flag to true, and reset it when the action is performed.

Comment: Thank you Daouse. Even if I use first time flag say "isLoaded, setIsLoaded", and useEffect on "isLoaded", again it's a Async operation and I am getting inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ref to toggle when the action is called, and avoid calling the action if the ref is `true` or nothing has changed from the initial values:

```
const initialIsApproved = false
const initialIsPlayer = false

const Demo = () => {
  const [isApproved, setIsApproved] = useState(initialIsApproved)
  const [isPlayer, setIsPlayer] = useState(initialIsPlayer)
  
  const called = useRef(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!called.current // would abort if the ref is true
       && isApproved !== initialIsApproved
       && isPlayer !== initialIsPlayer) {
      called.current = true // set the ref to true
      getDetails(isApproved, isPlayer)
    }
  }, [isApproved, isPlayer])
  
  return (...)
}
```